# How to get id in url when I am getting data from backend in React?

Tags: reactjs

[image: It is showing error like this] I am working on a crud operation in React project, In my project I have done a post and get Api's

Successfully. Now I am trying to get data by id in another component. But I am getting this kind

of error TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined. Please help me to solve this

error. All API is working fine

This is App.js

```
import React from 'react';
// import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Navbar from './Components/Navbar/Navbar';
import Home from './Pages/Home/Home';
import Signup from './Pages/Signup/Signup';
import List from './Pages/List/List';
import Editstudentdetails from './Pages/Editstudentdetaills/Editstudentdetails'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Navbar></Navbar>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/'><Home></Home></Route>
          <Route path='/signup'><Signup></Signup></Route>
          <Route path='/list'><List></List></Route>
          <Route path='/:id/editstudentdetails'><Editstudentdetails></Editstudentdetails></Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is List.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './List.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

function List(props) {
    const [data, setData] = useState([])

    const getData = async () => {
        try {
            const result = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/signup')
            setData(result.data)
            console.log(result.data)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getData()
    }, [])


    return (
        <div className='container'>
            <div className='row'>
                <div className='col-12'>
                    <div className='list'>
                        <table className="table table-bordered">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Firstname</th>
                                    <th>Lastname</th>
                                    <th>Email</th>
                                    <th>Password</th>
                                    <th>Edit</th>
                                    <th>Delete</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                {data.map(currentValue =>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>{currentValue.firstname}</td>
                                        <td>{currentValue.lastname}</td>
                                        <td>{currentValue.email}</td>
                                        <td>{currentValue.password}</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <Link to='/id:/editstudentdetails'>
                                                <button className='btn btn-primary'>Edit</button>
                                            </Link>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <button className='btn btn-danger'>Delete</button>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                )}
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default List
```

This is Editstudentdetails.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './Editstudentdetails.css';
import axios from 'axios';

function Editstudentdetails(props) {
    const [getStudentDataById,setStudentDataById] = useState({})

    const { id } = props.match.params.id

    const getDataById = async() => {
        try {
            const result = await axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/api/signup/${id}`)
            setStudentDataById(result.data)
            console.log(result.data)
        } catch(error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getDataById()
    }, [])

    const handleChange = ({target}) => {
        const { name, value } = target
    }
    return (
        <div className='container'>
            <div className='row'>
                <div className='col-4'>
                    <form>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="firstname">Firstname</label>
                            <input type="text" className="form-control" id="firstname"></input>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="lastname">Lastname</label>
                            <input type="text" className="form-control" id="lastname"></input>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                            <input type="email" className="form-control" id="email"></input>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                            <input type="password" className="form-control" id="password"></input>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Editstudentdetails
```

If you feel I am not clear with my doubt, please put a comment.

Comment: try `const { id } = props.match.params`

Comment: Try to post the error trace or a screenshot of it, as we don't know this "Cannot read property 'params' of undefined" happens in which place or which file?!

Comment: Which line causes the error? And what is the full error.

Comment: Hi @Code-Apprentice the error is in Editstudentdetails.js and line number is 8 in the screen shot.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show which line causes the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using hooks, you can use `useParams` hook from `react-router-dom`

```js
const { id } = useParams()
```

or wrap your component with `withRouter` also from `react-router-dom` and fix your destructuring assignment

```js
const { id } = props.match.params

export default withRouter(Editstudentdetails)
```

You also need to pass the id to the `Link` url

```js
<Link to={`/${currentValue.id}/editstudentdetails`}>
```

Comment: Hi @Asaf Aviv When I Click the edit button why it is not getting the document id in the url it is simply showing like this ---- http://localhost:3000/id:/editstudentdetails. I need an id in the url when I click edit button.

Comment: @Vamsi Yes i see the problem now, i will edit the answer

Comment: Hi @ I tried your code now it is showing like this ---http://localhost:3000/undefined/editstudentdetails

Comment: Thank you very much @Asaf Aviv I have to do like this <Link to={`/${currentValue._id}/editstudentdetails`}>

Answer (score 1):

I think you have something wrong with destructure,

try to replace this :

```
const { id } = props.match.params.id
```

with this :

```
const { id } = props && props.match && props.match.params && props.match.params
```